# remaining queries are running event after rollback in a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, transactions

I have a function to make a transaction as below

```
utils.sqlTransaction = function (event, callback) {

    let connection = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);
    let queryItemPosition = 0;
    let queriesData = event;
    let resultData = [];
    function queryItem() {
        if (queryItemPosition > (queriesData.length - 1)) {
            connection.commit(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function () {
                        return callback("Error in processing request commit");
                    });
                }
                connection.end();
                return callback(null, resultData);
            });
        } else {
            let queryData = queriesData[queryItemPosition] ? queriesData[queryItemPosition].queryData : {};
            let parsedQuery = utils.getQuery(queriesData[queryItemPosition].query, queryData);

            if (parsedQuery == false) {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                    return callback("\nQuery :-> " + event.query + " <-:  not Found!!");
                });
            }

            connection.query(parsedQuery, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function () {
                        return callback(err);
                    });
                }
                resultData.push(result);
                queryItemPosition++;
                queryItem();
            })

        }
    }

    connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }
        queryItem();
    });
}
```

I pass data to it as

```
[{
        "query": "some_query",
        "queryData": {}
}, 
{
        "query": "someother_query",
        "queryData": {}
}]
```

So that array of queries it handles. But on error even if I call `.rollback`, it is executing remaining queries. Please help me solve this issue.

NOTE: I am using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package

Thanks...

Comment: The loop just continues if there is an error (and rollback). You should `return` after you rollback in `if (parsedQuery == false)`.

Comment: @Vatev, I am returning inside the rollback function right. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, and that returns you from the rollback callback to nowhere. The outer function (queryItem ) just continues after the `if(parsedQuery == false)`.

Comment: Thanks @Vatev. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because rollback happens as an async function,  but your code doesn't wait for it. Change your code to something like:

```
if (err) {
     connection.rollback(function () {
           return callback("Error in processing request commit");
     });
}
else {
    connection.end();
    return callback(null, resultData);
}
```

Similar for all other parts of your code, like:

```
 if (parsedQuery == false) {
       connection.rollback(function () {
           return callback("\nQuery :-> " + event.query + " <-:  not Found!!");
       });
 }
 else {
      // continue rest of code here
 }
```

This way the successful flow of your code won't execute in case of errors.